# Error in eval(expr = expr) : object 'nFeature_RNA_lower' not found

Tags: r, function, seurat

I am extremely confused as to why this code keeps throwing an error.

```
qc_and_normalize <- function(seurat_object, coeff=3) {

  nCount_RNA_upper <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA) + coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA)

  nFeature_RNA_upper <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA) +   coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA)

  nCount_RNA_lower <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA) - coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA)

  nFeature_RNA_lower <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA) - coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA)


  dims <- seurat_object@assays$RNA@counts@Dim

  dims_lower_cut <- sum((seurat_object$nCount_RNA < nCount_RNA_lower) & (seurat_object$nFeature_RNA < nFeature_RNA_lower))
  dims_upper_cut <- sum((seurat_object$nCount_RNA > nCount_RNA_upper) & (seurat_object$nFeature_RNA > nFeature_RNA_upper))
  print(paste0('removing ', round((dims_lower_cut + dims_upper_cut) / dims[2] * 100, 2), '% of samples'))

  # QC
  # remove "bad cells"
  seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, ( nFeature_RNA > nFeature_RNA_lower | nCount_RNA > nCount_RNA_lower) 
                          & (nCount_RNA < nCount_RNA_upper | nFeature_RNA < nFeature_RNA_upper))


  # normalize data
  # by default, normalization.method = "LogNormalize", scale.factor = 10000
  seurat_object <- NormalizeData(seurat_object)

  return(seurat_object)
}
```

The function is not that important, it's just when it reaches the line

```
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, ( nFeature_RNA > nFeature_RNA_lower | nCount_RNA > nCount_RNA_lower) 
                          & (nCount_RNA < nCount_RNA_upper | nFeature_RNA < nFeature_RNA_upper))
```

it throws the error

```
Error in eval(expr = expr) : object 'nFeature_RNA_lower' not found
```

Why can't it find `nFeature_RNA_lower` when it was defined in the function? When I try to print it a line above the error line, it prints it without a problem. Everything works also when I run the code line by line in the global environment, but when I make it into a function it suddenly can't find `nFeature_RNA_lower`.

This is extremely confusing, can someone please help me understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the subset function mistakes that for a column in the object, for example:

```
neu = function(x){
 cutoff = 3
 subset(x,nFeature_RNA>cutoff)
 }

neu(pbmc_small)
Error in eval(expr = expr) : object 'cutoff' not found
```

You can subset by the matrix:

```
neu = function(x){
cutoff = 3
x[,x@meta.data$nFeature_RNA>cutoff]
}
neu(pbmc_small)
An object of class Seurat 
230 features across 80 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (230 features)
 2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, tsne
```

Looking at the function you have, we can also simplify it a bit, first we define the samples with want to exclude:

```
foo = function(features,coeff){
  m = apply(features,2,function(i){
    abs(i - median(i)) > coeff*mad(i)
  })
  rowMeans(m) == 1
}
```

Then it's a matter of using this in the main function you have:

```
qc_and_normalize <- function(seurat_object, coeff=2) {
  exclude = foo(seurat_object@meta.data[,c("nCount_RNA","nFeature_RNA")],coeff)
  seurat_object <- seurat_object[,!exclude]
  seurat_object <- NormalizeData(seurat_object)
  return(seurat_object)
}
```

We can test it:

```
qc_and_normalize(pbmc_small,2)
Performing log-normalization
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
An object of class Seurat 
230 features across 77 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (230 features)
 2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, tsne
```

Check it using your code:

```
seurat_object = pbmc_small
nCount_RNA_upper <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA) + coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA)
nFeature_RNA_upper <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA) +   coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA)
nCount_RNA_lower <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA) - coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nCount_RNA)
nFeature_RNA_lower <- median(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA) - coeff*mad(seurat_object@meta.data$nFeature_RNA)

  dims_lower_cut <- sum((seurat_object$nCount_RNA < nCount_RNA_lower) & (seurat_object$nFeature_RNA < nFeature_RNA_lower))
  dims_upper_cut <- sum((seurat_object$nCount_RNA > nCount_RNA_upper) & (seurat_object$nFeature_RNA > nFeature_RNA_upper))

dims_lower_cut
[1] 0
> dims_upper_cut
[1] 3
```